# Is it possible to develop a login xpages base on Lotus Notes Email Client Account?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I would like to develop a web application using IBM Lotus Domino Designer 8.5.2.

The web application shall verify user's authentication base on user's Lotus Notes email account information.

More information about Lotus Notes in case it is helpful, users using Lotus Notes as email client, they check email using Lotus Notes. Their given email address like username@companyname.com

Here is my plan, the web application requires the user to enter the username and password to login.

The username and the password should be the same account as the user login to Lotus Notes for email checking, for example, to login to Lotus Notes email client, the username is **testusername** and the password is **testpassword**.

The user should enter the same username and the password to login to the web application  (that is testusername for username and testpassword
for password).

Before I post my question, I read the article in this website
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_in_the_Notes_Client-Security 
and I get confuse that should I have 1 or more database for the web application ? 
But I just want the web application has a simple login.

Is it possible to develop a web application just use Lotus Notes Email Client account to login?

If so, I guess the validation should perform in xpages, is it correct?

I should be grateful if you would give advice or suggestion on this issue.

Thank you very much.

Yours sincerely,

beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login process is a server based process and not based on the database directly.
First of all the Domino- server you try to access has to be configured to use a session based login, otherwise you are not able to use a login page and might be asked for your Login- Credentials multiple times in one sesssion.

Please ask your Domino- Administrator to do this.

Second: Usually there is a "domcfg.nsf" on the server to configure the login- forms. Without that you would just see an ugly yellow page with username and password- prompt.

Third: The users in the domino directory need to have an "Internet Password" set in their person document. This can be done manually or by synching the Notes ID password to the internet password using a policy (again: ask your admin, how it is configured in your environment)

Last (but not least): The acl of your application containing your XPage needs to have a proper ACL set (do not allow anonymous access).

If all of that requirements are met, you will be automatically prompted for a password when trying to accesss your XPage application, and after that be redirected to the reuqested page.

In a next step you can customize the Login page to fit the design of your XPage or even write a new login- page using XPages.

Security is by default built into domino, you just have to use it...